# ionic2 datepicker current date

Tags: datepicker, ionic2

I am new to Ionic2.

Is there any way to display showing current date in **ionic2** of **datepicker** ?? I mean current date ***won't show*** before datepicker's pick.It will only show only when datepicker apears. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please provide a code snipped of what you already tried?

Answer (score 0):

Try mapping the datepicker model to a variable which holds the current date:

```
<ion-datetime [(ngModel)]="currentDate" /></ion-datetime
```

and in your controller:

```
var currentDate = new Date();
```

here's an example :

> https://codesundar.com/ionic2-tutorial/ionic-2-date-picker-example/

Answer (score 0):

```
<ion-datetime (ionChange)="changeDate()" displayFormat="MMMM YYYY" pickerFormat="MMMM YYYY" [(ngModel)]="filterdate"></ion-datetime>
```

and in your ts file

```
 filterdate = this.today.toISOString();
```